# Checking if an Azure Storage Queue exists

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I would like to check if an Azure Storage Queue exists by calling the `Azure.Storage.Queues.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)` method within the Azure Storage v12 API. I am trying to do this via SAS tokens as per business requirements, but I am getting an authorization error as below:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
Status: 403 
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
```

In the stack trace I can see that this line throws the error within the API:

```
Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueRestClient.GetPropertiesAsync(Nullable`1 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am using the API as shown below:

```
var serviceQueueClient = new QueueClient(GetServiceSasToken());
return await serviceQueueClient.ExistsAsync(); // this line throws the exception

private Uri GetServiceSasToken()
{
    var queueSasBuilder = new QueueSasBuilder()
    {
        ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
        QueueName = _queueName, // Name of my queue, which exists on Azure Portal
        Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
    };

    queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(QueueSasPermissions.Read | QueueSasPermissions.Add | QueueSasPermissions.Process);
    StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new(_accountName, _accountKey); // storage account name, and the access key
    var sasQueryParams = queueSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(storageSharedKeyCredential).ToString();
    return new UriBuilder()
    {
        Scheme = "https",
        Host = $"{_accountName}.queue.core.windows.net",
        Path = _queueName,
        Query = sasQueryParams
    }.Uri;
}
```

I have also tried using an Account SAS token as below, but this also fails with the same error.

```
var serviceQueueClient = new QueueClient(GetAccountSasToken());
return await serviceQueueClient.ExistsAsync(); // this line throws the exception

private Uri GetAccountSasToken()
{
    var queueSasBuilder = new AccountSasBuilder()
    {
        Services = AccountSasServices.Queues,
        ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.Service | AccountSasResourceTypes.Container | AccountSasResourceTypes.Object,
        ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
        Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
    };

    queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.Create | AccountSasPermissions.List | AccountSasPermissions.Read);
    StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new(_accountName, _accountKey); // storage account name, and the access key
    var sasQueryParams = queueSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(storageSharedKeyCredential).ToString();
    return new UriBuilder()
    {
        Scheme = "https",
        Host = $"{_accountName}.queue.core.windows.net",
        Path = _queueName,
        Query = sasQueryParams
    }.Uri;
}
```

I managed to manipulate Azure Blobs in a similar way within the same kubernetes pod, so the private endpoint should be working okay in my environment.
What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you use `QueueSasBuilder.SetPermissions( "rwlaup" )`?

Comment: Then the error turns into `Make sure the authorization header is formed correctly including the signature`. When I call `queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(QueueSasPermissions.All)` (which also didn't work) the Permissions property end up being `raup`, so I think `rwlaup` is an invalid permission setting for queues.

Comment: What's the output of `GetServiceSasToken()` method? Basically what's the URI that gets passed to `QueueClient` constructor?

Comment: The resulting uri is `https://<accountName>.queue.core.windows.net/<queueName>?sv=2021-12-02&spr=https&se=2023-03-24T12%3A38%3A00Z&sp=raup&sig=<signature>`

Comment: Your SAS URL looks ok. Can you try to perform some other operation using this? May be peek messages from the queue?

Comment: `QueueClient.GetPropertiesAsync()` and `QueueClient.ReceiveMessageAsync()` also returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I received the same error.

[image]

You are facing this issue because the storage account has Firewall enabled.

[image]

Make sure you add your IP address ranges to allow access from the internet or your on-premises networks.

[image]

After following the above I could get the expected result.

[image]